# Is a sub-query executed when the condition is false?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have this query:

```
select *, 
     case when p.amount is null then '1'
          else (select count(1) 
                  from Money_paid mp 
                where mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id limit 1)
     end paid
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id
```

As you see, there is a sub query in the `else` part of `case .. when` function. Now I want to know, when `p.amount is null` is `true` then that sub query executes?

---

I asked that because I can implement that `case .. when` function by PHP codes and remove it from my query, So my query will be like this:

```
select *, 
    (select count(1) from Money_paid mp 
        where mp.post_id = p.id and
              mp.user_id = :user_id and
              p.amount is not null
        limit 1) paid
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id

// and some php code to implement that condition
```

---

In conclusion, if that sub query executes for both cases (`p.amount is null` = `true` and `p.amount is null` = `false`) then I will go with second query (without `case .. when`). But it that sub query **only** executes when that condition is `false`, then I will go with first query.

So which one?

Comment: sorry, but why don't you just try it by yourself?

Comment: @low_rents How can I figure it out by myself?

Comment: by putting an update- or insert-query at that position.

Comment: @low_rents emm, seems reasonable `:-)` thank you

Comment: nevermind - i wouldn't have known the answer to this question by myself - but i just would have tried ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** , the `ELSE` won't be executed unless no other condition is true.

`CASE EXPRESSION` is evaluating all his conditions one by one by the order you've put them, so when the first condition is met , the case breaks.

> - A CASE expression evaluates to the first true condition.
> - If there is no true condition, it evaluates to the ELSE part.
> - If there is no true condition and no ELSE part, it evaluates to NULL.

Comment: So that sub query **only** executes when `p.amount is null` condition is `false`, right?

Comment: If p.amount is rarely null, then it won't make much difference, but if it has more then a few null values, `CASE EXPRESSION` will save a lot of unnecessary selects. @stack